# What method(s) do computers or calculators use to solve polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, programming

I want to make a program that will solve polynomials, but I don't want to just look at another program that already works as I think that would defeat the purpose of the exercise.

And that's why I'm asking the question here instead of on Stack Overflow.

I think it would be very difficult to implement Alpha-Beta Theory/Veita's Formula, and guessing using Factoring doesn't seem like a neat solution to me, so I'm wondering if there is in fact an easier implementation.

I would also like this to be scalable for higher degree polynomials if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Find the extrema (i.e., find the roots of the derivative), evaluate at the extrema and check for sign changes at successive extrema (and before the first one and after the last one), then use Newton’s method over that interval whenever that happens.

Comment: I would personally rather implement some type of symbolic solver as that is more trendy nowadays than a strictly numeric approximator.